# Chips Value get [object Object]

Tags: javascript, laravel, materialize

i need to get data from chips

```
var testEmail = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@([A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;

var instance = M.Chips.getInstance($('.chips'));
var email_address = instance.chipsData;
alert(email_address ); // Show [object Object]
```

my html Form

```
<div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal--blocks">
                    <div class="small--heading">
                        <form class="col s12">
                            <div class="input-field">
                                <div id="chipgetval" class="chips"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-field-btn">
                                <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="button" id="send_email">Send Email</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Can you help me why show [object Object] Value ?

Comment: Dupe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39556138/get-data-from-materialize-css-chips

Comment: [More dupes](https://www.google.com/search?q=Chips.getInstance+site:stackoverflow.com) ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting [object Object] is you are passing object directly to html you need to loop through the object in JS

Like in below line **data** is the name object,**0** is for the index in array and **chipName** is the key of object to access the key value

alert(data[0].chipName);

hope it may help